# Will The Fanatic encounter stay in the same place?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

If the Fanatic is encountered in a dungeon and you retreat from combat, will the Fanatic be encountered if you return to that same tile?

The specific use case here is:

1. Start dungeon
2. Encounter Fanatic
3. Retreat.

At this point, after the retreat:

- The game threw me back to the room before the corridor with the Fanatic
- The tile the Fanatic was encountered on still has the red X icon.

So, will the Fanatic spawn if that tile is stepped on again?

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](https://darkestdungeon.gamepedia.com/The_Fanatic)

> If you decide to run away from the Fanatic, he will appear in the
>   next encounter, fulfilling his promise to hunt "the Cursed" down.

So, you will meet him again immediately after retreating, even if you were to go to a different room in the dungeon with a monster encounter, you would meet the fanatic there again. If you feel, your party isn't up to handling the Fanatic, you should retreat from the entire dungeon.

Comment: This is not accurate. I went the other direction, encountering at least 6 fights and 6 rooms (clearing additional to recoup monetary loses). However, I did not have the courage to test if the fanatic would spawn on the same square. So, the question remains unanswered.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the wiki goes on further to say "Attempting to retreat without abandoning the expedition is hopeless, as the Fanatic will simply appear in the next encounter." This is also inaccurate, per my anecdote in the previous comment. Perhaps it was changed in a patch at some point.